# changing root URL for all images in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I recently migrated a live wordpress site, watershedgeo.com, over to a development site using the temp url, http://vps3813.inmotionhosting.com/~watershedgeo/dev.watershedgeo.com/.

I finally got it launched but the images and links don't show, they're all broken, but a lot of the images are showing their alt text. Here's the weird thing:

If I inspect the images in chrome, they show the temp url as the src of the image, but if I change the root before wp-content to watershedgeo.com, they show up. However, if I inspect the images on the live site, they show the source as http://1qy8tt40p7n9v7tao3knw537.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/imageName

Is there a plugin or a way that I can change it so all the images use 1qy8tt40p7n9v7tao3knw537.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com as the root so the images can show for development? All folders match, it's just the root that needs to be changed

Comment: If its not too late and you have haven't already changes, (or for future reference) I suggest using the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin. It builds an archive that you copy to the new site and install, and it takes care of everything including changing the urls.

Comment: Wait, so if the live site is using the wp engine URL in the front end then it would cause the new site to as well? Would this be affected with the temp URL in the wp database or wp configuration file?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? The Duplicator plugin allows you made a complete, isolated copy of a WP site - including updating all URLs to the new domain - in order to move a site from development to production for example. The copy you made is acting in a rather bizarre way, so I'd suggest just starting again with a new copy using Duplicator as it will automatically make sure all the URLs are updated correctly.

Comment: ok, sorry for the confusion but that's basically what I meant. Originally, I copied all the files over in my cPanel file manager and cloned the database in cpanel, only changing the site url in my database and the database and site url values in wp-config.php. I'll try this and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be difficult to catch everything when you're copying it manually. I'd be lost without the Duplicator plugin! You might run into a couple of small issues but the only problem I usually run into is that building the archive can time out due to setting on my hosting. If that happens, I exclude the `uploads` folder from the build and manually copy it across - it shouldn't contain anything that needs updating. If you do have any problems, come back and ping me with a comment :-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Change it Like this

IMPORTANT POINT: first check the comment on question..

My Code:

```
<?php 
function kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon)
{        
    $new_url =  "https://example.com/alibaba/ccc/";
    foreach($image as $index => $url) {
        $image[$index] = $new_url;
    }
    return $image;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_image_src', 10, 4);
function kdev_redirect_wp_calculate_image_srcset($sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id) {
    $new_url =  "https://example.com/alibaba/ccc/";
    foreach($sources as $key => $source) {
        $sources[$key]['url'] = $new_url;
    }
    return $source;
}
add_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'kdev_redirect_wp_calculate_image_srcset', 10, 5);

function kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($url, $id) {
    $new_url =  "https://example.com/alibaba/ccc/";
    return $new_url;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_thumb_url', 'kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_thumb_url', 10, 2);

function kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_image_attributes($attr) {
    $new_url =  "https://example.com/alibaba/ccc/";
    $attr['src'] = $new_url;
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'kdev_redirect_wp_get_attachment_image_attributes');
```

?>